# Microsoft Search Server deletes indexes of offline data source

Tags: search, microsoft-search-server

I'm making a full documents search at office, but many computers are not powered on all the time. Microsoft Search Server 2008 delete all the data it indexed before, if this PC is offline during next crawl.

Is there the way to say Microsoft Search Server not to crawl data source, if it is offline?